# Two Way Dependend Dropdown in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two excel sheets in a workbook Sheet1 and Sheet2. In sheet 1 I have Vertical[Column A] and Resource[Column B] where I want the resultant dependent dropdown. In Sheet2 I have Resource[Column A] and Vertical[Column B] where resource and verticals are filled.

What I want is in Sheet1 if I select any Vertical the Resource should automatically filled and if I select Resource then respective Vertical should get auto filled.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: If you want autofill then use `VLOOKUP()` or `XLOOKUP()` function.

Answer (score 1):

Using formulas only, you could get to this point:

User would select Vertical / Resource in Column A / B, and Excel can populate the matches in Column D & E.

This does have limitations - if the user selects both a Vertical and a Resource, only the Resource will be considered. The user would have to clear the Resource selection if they want to use the Vertical selection.

In D2 use the following:

```
=IFS(
B2<>"",INDEX(Sheet2!$B:$B,MATCH(B2,Sheet2!$A:$A,0)),
A2<>"",A2,
TRUE,"")
```

In E2 use the following:

```
=IFS(
B2<>"",B2,
A2<>"",INDEX(Sheet2!$A:$A,MATCH(A2,Sheet2!$B:$B,0)),
TRUE,"")
```

To get the dropdown list in A2, click Data Validation, Allow: List, and select the range on Sheet2 with your Verticals.

To get the dropdown list in B2, click Data Validation, Allow: List, and select the range on Sheet2 with your Resources.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is it possible [from your screenshot] that if I select value in column A the value in column B should auto-pupulate and vice versa without column D and E since I already have those fully filled/mapped in Sheet2 for reference?

Comment: It is not possible with formulas. You can either put a formula in Column A that depends on Column B, or you can put a formula in Column B that depends on Column A. You cannot put two formulas that depend on each other, that is called a circular reference.

You can do what you want with VBA if that's an option for you.